# Server on linux made in C - dual ports with different behavior

Tags: c, linux, sockets, terminal, server

I must make a server and a client on linux in C. The server must serve the concurent clients but i have a problem. It must also have a second port that an admin could connect to modify some files and i don't know how to open the same server on 2 ports. Moreover if the admin connect lets say on port 2080 he should have only his options while if the user connects on 2081 he should have different options. I already tried making 2 socket descriptors, binding them and listening on them but it crashes. Unfortunately i can't put any code on the platform as i am forbiden to do so. Please help me figure it out :D

Comment: Can the admin not just log in using the same port, but with different/additional authentication?

Comment: 'i can't put any code on the platform as i am forbiden to do so' - what does that mean?

Comment: If you HAVE to service two ports, you MUST use two servers. They can be in the same app if you want, eg. using two listener threads, one for each port.

Comment: it is a faculty project so they check for plagiarism... i must do with 2 ports. that is what they ask from me -_-

Comment: Well if your school is that strict, you're not allowed to use any answers you get here, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two thread with server as routine.pass port as local variable to thread.